# Trying to scrape data by passing the URL from database but throws error

Tags: r, rvest

I am scraping data from website by passing URL from database and parsing into R.Below is my code

```
base_url_2 <- sqldf('select ORG_IMMEDIATE_PARENT_SRC from OA_output where row_id=1 ')


df <- lapply(base_url_2,function(u)

    {
    try({

        html_obj <- read_html(u)
        draft_table <- html_nodes(html_obj,'table') 
        cik <- substr(u,start = 41,stop = 47) 
        draft1 <- html_table(draft_table,fill = TRUE) 
        final <- c(cik,draft1) 

    })
})


check <- sapply(df, class) != "try-error"
df <- df[check] 


data <- melt(df)
data <- as.data.frame(data,row.names = NULL)
data <- data[,1:2]
names(data) <- c("CIK","Company") 

data2 <- transform(data, CIK = na.locf(CIK ))

options(max.print = 5.5e5)
```

When I am trying to run the above code it throws the below error:

> Error in doc_parse_file(con, encoding = encoding, as_html = as_html,
>   options = options) : Expecting a single string value: [type=character;
>   extent=455].

Please help me with the code

Comment: Where exactly does it throw that error? And from the error msg, it seems there a too many character values at hand. So you would have to select one of those values.

Comment: The error comes when I am running the loop.How can I select those values ?

Comment: Maybe go through the loop step by step and check the outputs. I suspect read_html gets more than 1 URL and throws the error then.

Comment: I am using the loop to scrape data from around 50 URL's

Comment: could you post a `dput(base_url_2)` or `str(base_url_2)` result?